# TypeError: Failed to load plugin 'jest' declared in '.eslintrc': Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint, babel-jest, react-scripts

I was updating react-scripts to latest version i.e. 5.0.0 and started seeing above error.
One article suggested to upgrade @typescript-eslint to version ^5.0.0 in order to be compatible with eslint version ^8.3.0 which comes by default by updating react-scripts to 5.0.0, which I did but error still exists.
Please help as it is a critical issue as build is failing.

Comment: Did you find your answer? I have the same issue now.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably too late for the OP but I'm hoping this helps people like me who are looking for answers.

What worked for me was to update this library: `eslint-plugin-jest` to v26.x

I saw [other people](https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/issues/982#issuecomment-967437871) post saying that you need to update `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin` and `@typescript-eslint/parser` to v5.x, however that did not work for me (but wanted to include it in case it helps someone else)

Comment: I did the same but I also updated eslint-plugin-import to 2.26.0 to solve the issue