# ng lint no longer working after updating to angular 14 from angular 13

Tags: angular, eslint

After updating my app from **angular 13.3.2** to **angular 14** using `ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@14` I start getting the next error when using `ng lint`:

> class CLIEngine extends eslint_1.CLIEngine {
>
> TypeError: Failed to load plugin 'jest' declared in
> '.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]': Class extends value undefined is not a
> constructor or null

Since I don't know exactly where to look, I share the **dependencies** on my **package.json**:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "13.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "13.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "14.1.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "5.0.2",
    "@ngneat/until-destroy": "9.0.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "3.7.3",
    "rxjs": "7.5.2",
    "stream-browserify": "3.0.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "13.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.1.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "14.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "14.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.1.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "14.1.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.19",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/schematics": "0.0.1-alpha.5",
    "@types/chart.js": "2.9.37",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "15.12.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.34.0",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "1.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-import-meta": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "32.3.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "util": "0.12.4",
    "webpack": "5.70.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.4.2"
  }
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71781215/typeerror-failed-to-load-plugin-jest-declared-in-eslintrc-class-extends-v) of any help?

Comment: @MikeS. updating eslint-plugin-jest to 26.8.7 now gives me the next error when executing ng lint:
 Failed to load plugin 'eslint-plugin-import' declared in '.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]

Comment: Have you tried removing the `node_modules` folder altogether and re-installing all the packages afterwards?

Comment: Working with a VPN and not the best network that could be an issue. Doing a npm cache clean -f and re-installing for the moment. Maybe trying to delete and re-install next day at office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I did the next steps:

1. Update `eslint-plugin-jest` manually to `26.8.7`
2. Update `eslint-plugin-import` manually to `2.26.0`
3. `npm cache clean -f`
4. `npm i`